# Ajuda com Diretiva de Máscara para números com 4 casas decimais no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angularjs

Quero fazer uma diretiva de números no angularJS com duas funcionalidades, uma para formatar ao digitar um número em um input do html.

Exemplo de como gostaria : 

 1.200,0000
      12.000,0000
      120.000,0000

e a outra para limitar as casas decimais em 4 casas após a virgula.

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o `ng-currency`? Ex: http://plnkr.co/edit/u9mJqDH8UpwxDnOv8gZL?p=preview

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, porém testei aqui e não funcinou o exemplo, adicionei o script do ng-currency, e eu tenho o locale pt-br, no console não acusa nenhum erro, tem alguma config a mais pra adicionar?

Comment: Você colocou a diretiva em seu html? Declarou ela no app?

Comment: `angular.module('myApp', ['ng-currency']);`

Comment: Perfeito, tinha me esquecido deste detalhe, funcionou certinho, muito obrigado.

Comment: Por nada, já que funcionou vou responder a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [ng-currency](https://github.com/aguirrel/ng-currency), com essa biblioteca você pode formatar suas casas decimais. [Aqui](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9mJqDH8UpwxDnOv8gZL?p=preview) está um exemplo simples de como utilizar a biblioteca.